# "to resolve" or "to resolving"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> I have a good reason to resolving my question.

> I have a good reason to resolve my question.

Comment: the ing one is wrong. This is easily seen in Word or even google.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first sentence is wrong while the second is correct. The noun "reason" usually isn't paired with preposition "to". The following would be correct:

> I have a good reason for resolving my question.

In the second sentence, "to" is not a preposition but part of the full infinitive verb "to resolve". The noun "reason" is often paired with a full infinitive.

Comment: Why down-vote, I'm not a native speaker. OK, what is the difference between `I have a good reason to resolve my question`  and `I have a good reason for resolving my question.` ?

Comment: @user2925716 You're asking me why someone else downvoted your question? I'm not sure.

Comment: @user2925716 They mean the same thing.

Comment: @user2925716 It doesn't appear that anyone did down-vote your question. Anyway I'm up-voting it. In answer to the question in your comment - there is no difference in meaning whatever.